# Loop to import and save each stock with its respective name through Yahoo Finance

Tags: python, loops, yahoo-finance, pandas-datareader

I have a doubt:
I am using Yahoo Finance to import information about some stocks. I have a "ticker" list where I have the names of the stocks to import and I use pdr.get_data_yahoo. My code is the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import pandas_datareader as pdr 

ticker = ['AAPL', 'AMZN', 'FB'] # Acciones

start = dt.datetime(2020, 11, 21) # Desde
end = dt.datetime(2020, 12, 4) # Hasta

AAPL = pdr.get_data_yahoo('AAPL', start = start, end = end) # a)
AMZN = pdr.get_data_yahoo('AMZN', start = start, end = end) # b)
FB   = pdr.get_data_yahoo('FB', start = start, end = end) # c)
```

Instead of importing stock by stock as in a), b) and c), how could I do a loop or iteration to save the information of each action in a variable with its respective name (equal to the str of the ticker). That is, I want to be able to modify and / or add actions to the ticker and that each one is saved with its respective name

I was trying a loop like

```
ticker = ['AAPL', 'AMZN', 'FB', 'MSFT', 'AAL']
for ticker in tickers:
ticker[i] = pdr.get_data_yahoo(ticker, start = start, end = end)
```

Comment: create a dictionary with ticker names as keys and the dataframe as values, then you can refer each key to get each dataframe something like : `my_dfs = {ticker: pdr.get_data_yahoo(ticker, start = start, end = end) for ticker in tickers}` , then do `my_dfs['AAPL']` to get the respective dataframe

Comment: you can't use `ticker[i]` because `ticker` is list, not dictionary. you have change list to dictionary or use other dictionary `result = {}` and `result[i] =  pdr.get_data_yahoo(ticker, start = start, end = end)`

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems

- first: `ticker` is list so you can't use it as dictonary `ticker[i]`.
- second: you use `tickers` (with `s`) but you don't have this variable.

You simply mess two similar names. I will use name `all_tickers` and `ticker` to better show problem.

And use dictionary for results

```
all_tickers = ['AAPL', 'AMZN', 'FB', 'MSFT', 'AAL']
results = {}

for ticker in all_tickers:
    results[ticker] = pdr.get_data_yahoo(ticker, start=start, end=end)
```

---

**EDIT:**

Don't use variables `AAPL`, `AMZN` and `FB` but keep it in dictinary as `results["AAPL"]`, `results["AMZN"]`, `results["FB"]`

Usually you will work with all tickets like this

```
for ticker in all_tickers:
    print(ticker, results[ticker])
```

or

```
max_value = {}

for ticker in all_tickers:
    max_value[ticker] = max( results[ticker] )
    #print('max value for', ticker, 'is', max_value[ticker])

for ticker in all_tickers:
    print('max value for', ticker, 'is', max_value[ticker])
```

or

```
my_favorite = ['AMZN', 'FB']

for ticker in my_favorite:
    print(ticker, results[ticker])
```

etc.

If you add new `ticket` to `all_tickers` then rest code will work the same.

---

Eventually you could add all to `pandas.DataFrame` and then you could work with all values even without `for`-loop.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply Furas.
But how could you make the information of each stock be saved in a variable with the name of the stock (the same name that appears in the ticker) using a loop or an iteration?

For example from

ticker = ['AAPL', 'AMZN', 'FB']

Create three variables AAPL, AMZN and FB and in each one the information of that stock.
The idea is that then you can change or add items to the ticker and the loop can keep working

Comment: don't use variables `AAPL`, `AMZN` and `FB` but keep it in dictinary as `results["AAPL"]`, `results["AMZN"]` , `results["FB"]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary and save the ticker data with the ticker name in it.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import pandas_datareader as pdr 

ticker = ['AAPL', 'AMZN', 'FB'] # Acciones
ticker_data = {}
start = dt.datetime(2020, 11, 21) # Desde
end = dt.datetime(2020, 12, 4) # Hasta

for ticker in tickers:
    ticker_data[ticker] = pdr.get_data_yahoo(ticker, start = start, end = end)

print(ticker_data)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply Harshana Serasinghe. But how could you make the information of each stock be saved in a variable with the name of the stock (the same name that appears in the ticker) using a loop or an iteration? For example from ticker = ['AAPL', 'AMZN', 'FB'] Create three variables AAPL, AMZN and FB and in each one the information of that stock. The idea is that then you can change or add items to the ticker and the loop can keep working